# Gather distinct neighbors with smallest weight in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have my_table t

```
id in_node out_node weight   

  1  'A'      'B'    17
  2  'B'      'A'     4  
  3  'C'      'A'    35   
  4  'A'      'D'    26
  ... 
  5  'C'      'G'    33     
  6  'X'      'Z'    12  
  7  'Z'      'Y'    15    
  8  'X'      'Y'    42   
  9  'K'      'M'    66   
  ...
 10  'A'      'Z'    20
```

Desired behavior

```
select id, in_count, in_weight, out_count,out_weight from t where  id = 10
      10      3          65          2        27      
             2,3,4      4+35+26     6,7      12+15      
       (1 is duplicate)
```

Steps to count number of distinct in_neighbors:

- `$A: select in_node from t where id = 10`
- `@B: select id from t where in_node = $A or out_node = $A --select in neighbor ids (1,2,3,4,10)`
- ```
  @C: select in_node as that_node from t where id in (@B) -- ('A', 'B', 'C')      
     union all       
     select out_node as that_node from t where id in (@B)  --('A','B','Z','D')
  ```
- ```
  (count distinct @C)  --5 now we can subtract two ('A' and 'Z' nods) to get the number of neighbors from in_node side
  ```

  To count in_weight we should select sum(weight) from t where id in (2,3,4). We shouldn't count weight for id=1 because

  ```
  select in_node from t where id = 1     
  union all      
  select out_node from t where id = 1      
  --'A','B'
  ```

  produces the same set as

  ```
  select in_node from t where id = 2      
  union all     
  select out_node from t where id = 2     
  --'A','B'
  ```

  while

  ```
  select weight from t where id = 2
  ```

  is smaller than

  ```
  select weight from t where id = 1
  ```

Is it possible to do this sort of selects from Oracle PL SQL  or is it easier to just pass the result set to Java?

---

This table represents a graph. Vertices are `in_node` and `out_node`, `id` corresponds to the edge and `weight` corresponds to the weight of the edge. I want to find all neighbor edges along with their weights. If there are several edges connecting two vertices only the the lightest edge should be accounted for.

So, 'in_total' corresponds to the total sum of the weights of "distinct" neighbor edges. By distinct I mean lightest edge connecting two given vertices.

I am modelling maximum travel distance across a graph. Sometimes A-B route is reported several times. In this case I want to only pick one A-B route with the lightest weight.

Total weight of neighbors over the number of neighbors is a useful indicator of connectivity for my problem.

Comment: Does your @B query need to have an additional predicate of `or out_mode = $A`?

Comment: @Boneist Good call. I need `in_node = $A or out_node = $A`. I've corrected the question.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind how we derive the in_weight and out_weight columns. Also, why is the in_count 3 and the out_count 2? Please explain more about the logic.

Comment: @Boneist, I've edited the answer. I am looking at an edge and adjacent edges. Edge priority decreases with (1) Decrease of edge weight (2) Increase of the number of neighboring edges (3) Increase in total weight of shortest distinct adjacent edges.

Comment: Thanks for the added info. However, you still haven't explained the logic behind the in_weight, out_weight and why the in/out counts are 3 and 2 respectively. I think I understand why the in_weight is 15, but why is the out_weight 17?

Comment: @Boneist That was a typo. Corrected it.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a "rolling window" or "rolling range."  Example at the bottom of here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533874200346716561

Comment: Ok, so to get the out* columns, we repeat the same steps as the in* columns, but taking the original out_node as the starting point. Gotcha.

Comment: @JBC this isn't a rolling range problem.

Comment: @Boneist correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a hierarchical query to get the neighbouring nodes and then summing accordingly:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'A' in_node, 'B' out_node, 17 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 2 ID, 'B' in_node, 'A' out_node, 4 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 3 ID, 'C' in_node, 'A' out_node, 5 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 4 ID, 'A' in_node, 'D' out_node, 6 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 5 ID, 'C' in_node, 'G' out_node, 33 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 6 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 12 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 7 ID, 'Z' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 15 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 8 ID, 'X' in_node, 'Y' out_node, 42 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 9 ID, 'K' in_node, 'M' out_node, 66 weight FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 10 ID, 'A' in_node, 'Z' out_node, 20 weight FROM dual),
   res AS (SELECT ID,
                  in_node,
                  out_node,
                  weight,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () orig_in_node,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN out_node END) OVER () orig_out_node,
                  MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN ID END) OVER () orig_id,
                  CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ID = connect_by_root(ID) THEN in_node END) OVER () IN (in_node, out_node) THEN 'in'
                       ELSE 'out'
                  END direction_from_orig_node,
                  LEAST(in_node, out_node) node1,
                  GREATEST(in_node, out_node) node2,
                  row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY LEAST(in_node, out_node), GREATEST(in_node, out_node) ORDER BY weight) rn
           FROM   t
           START WITH ID = 10
           CONNECT BY NOCYCLE (PRIOR out_node IN (in_node, out_node)
                              OR PRIOR in_node IN (in_node, out_node))
                              AND LEVEL <= 2)
SELECT orig_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) in_count,
       nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'in' THEN weight END), 0) in_sum,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN node1||'~'||node2 END) out_count,
       nvl(SUM(CASE WHEN direction_from_orig_node = 'out' THEN weight END), 0) out_sum
FROM   res
WHERE  rn = 1
AND    ID != orig_id
GROUP BY orig_id;
```

which gives:

```
   ORIG_ID   IN_COUNT     IN_SUM  OUT_COUNT    OUT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10          3         15          2         27
```

And if the start id = 5, you get:

```
   ORIG_ID   IN_COUNT     IN_SUM  OUT_COUNT    OUT_SUM
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         5          1          5          0          0
```

Comment: How to replace `WHEN ID = 10` with `for each id in (select id from t)`?

Comment: You could do `when level = 1`, or maybe (especially if you’re wanting to run for more than one id in the `start with`) `when id = connect_by_root(id)`, although I won’t be able to test the latter myself until tomorrow.

Comment: `START WITH ID = 5` should return `5 1 5 0 0` because of `id=3`, but doesn't.

Comment: I've updated my answer that should give you what you need. All the start with id 5 needed was an `nvl()` around the sum columns to return 0 if nothing was found.

Comment: Seems like it won't work with multiple start with ids, though.

Comment: Now it works, thank you. I will wrap it in a function to work with multiple IDs. Can you recommend a book about all these `OVER`, `GREATEST`, `CONNECT BY NO CYCLE`

Comment: You can find everything in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html) (select the relevant version for your database from the drop down list). Basically, I've used: hierarchical queries (`connect by`, `nocycle`, `start with`, `connect_by_root`), analytic functions (`... over (...)`) and the `least` and `greatest` scalar functions.